# Value error while fitting model with keras fit()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

## make a bigger datased

X = tf.range(-100,100,4)
X

## Make labes for the dataset

y = X+10
y

#1. Create the model
model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)])

## 2. compile the model

model.compile(loss = tf.keras.losses.mae, optimizer= tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(), metrics=["mae"])

## 3. Fit the model

model.fit(X,y)

## This is the error I am getting:

**ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

in ()
8
9 # 3. Fit the model (this time we'll train for longer)
---> 10 model.fit(X,y)

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
1145           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
1146             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1147               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
1148             else:
1149               raise

ValueError: in user code:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 859, in train_step
    y_pred = self(x, training=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 228, in assert_input_compatibility
    raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" '

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential_23" (type Sequential).

Input 0 of layer "dense_33" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: (None,)

Call arguments received:
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None,), dtype=int32)
  • training=True
  • mask=None
```

**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)])
```

is missing an input shape. Try something like:

```
tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=X.shape(0)])
```

Or maybe:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=X.shape(0))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
```